# Bizarre NoClassDefFoundError when running in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've tried looking at all the other NoClassDefFoundError threads on here and elsewhere, but they all seem to be a different problem.

My activity refers to a custom FragmentPagerAdapter - let's call it MyFragmentPagerAdapter.

The Activity refers to it with:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.form_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

This all seems to compile and build perfectly well in Eclipse.  Eclipse can certainly find all the classes - it auto filled the import statement for me.

However, when I try and run the class in Android (emulator or device) I get a NoClassDefFoundError for MyFragmentPagerAdapter and (of course) the app crashes.

I've tried deleting the APK on the device and re-installing in case it was a deployment issue, but it didn't help.

This isn't to do with some 3rd party library - it's my own class that it fails to find!

I have also tried "cleaning" the Project.

I have extracted the apk and inspected the output of

```
dexdump classes.dex | grep PagerAdapter
```

and there are references to my class in there, so I can only assume the compiled class is getting itnot the apk - which makes me even more bemused.

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: No, I usually only sort proguard out towards the end of app dev.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDef refers to classes **that are referred by** your class (in this case "MyFragmentPagerAdapter") not to the class itself (that's the ClassNotFoundException).

Check the import you have in the class "MyFragmentPagerAdapter" and be sure that they are all in the classpath of your android application i.e. by checking the libs folder and (eventually) other android libraries you are referring to in your project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have checked and double checked the import statement.  I can find the compiled class in the bin folder under the correct package structure.  I am assuming this makes it into the final apk - is the a way I can confirm what classes are in there?

Comment: I have extracted the apk and inspected the output of "dexdump classes.dex | grep PagerAdapter" and there are references to my class in there, so I can only assume the compiled class is getting itnot the apk - which makes me even more bemused.

Comment: Interesting...You mean that the class PagerAdapter is there, did you check all other imports you have in your class (the "MyFragmentPagerAdapter") to be in the classes.dex?

Comment: Yes, the classes.dex also mentioned MyFragmentPagerAdapter - it looks like it's there...

Comment: Ok, Could you post the stacktrace with the exception?
Also, check the java compiler you are using, it shuould **not** be java 7 apparently.

Comment: Aha! In looking at the stack trace while preparing to post it - I noticed another entry (only a warning for some reason) that said it couldn't resolve the superclass of MyFragmentPagerAdapter, which, presumably would mean it couldn't load the MyFragmentPagerAdapter class - hence my error!  It looks like, for some reason, the support v4 jar isn't getting deployed properly.

Comment: Check that you are **not** using the java7 compiler